# Finding coordinates of the turning points of a curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the question "Find the coordinates of the turning points of the following curve and sketch the curve

Y = X^2(-2X - 4)"

Here is my attempt is this correct ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculations are correct but your sketch is wrong because (0,0) isn't a turning point there.

Comment: I'm not sure how the curve should look. Is there a rule to decide what shape the curve should be ?

Comment: As you found out that (0,0) is a turning point (maximum) the curve should change direction there. So the curve should go down to the right of (0,0).

Comment: Could you possibly show me how this should look ? Like a quick sketch ? (:

Comment: Actually it's fine I understand (: thanks.